# Set Ant Properties across multiple modules in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ant

I have an IntelliJ project with about a dozen modules.  Each module directory contains an ant `build.xml`.  Right now, I define certain required ant properties on each individual build file.

However, most of these definitions use the same property name and value.  Instead of defining some of these in literally a dozen different places, is there a way to define an ant property that is "global" to all of the modules and/or ant build files in the entire project?

My intelliJ version is Ultimate 2018.1.5.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-21752, it's not possible at the moment.